# Javascript/Jquery accessing element attributes in an iframe from within the child document

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to create a web app that displays chord charts for a number of songs. Each within it's own iframe on separate tabs. I'm using a jquery library.
Each chart uses ajax to interrogate a DB to get the data to display content. It calculates metrics such as header height, footer height, page height and width to for pagination. The javascript is running from within the iframe not from the parent.

The chord chart pages behave themselves when I load a page as a normal web page. But as soon as I open the page within an iframe, the page doesn't display correctly because I can't calculate the metrics on the page. It seems that some attributes are undefined.

I'm using the following code to get a "page" element (as an example) on the chart from within the iframe.

```
var x = window.parent.document.getElementById("iframe2");
if (x)  {var s = $(x).contents().find('#page'+ pagecounter) ;}
if (s) alert ($(s).attr("id"));
```

"s" is correctly identified and it's id is correctly displayed. So I know that the right element is selected.

However, (as a few examples),

```
$(s).offset().top = 0 //when it should be 5
$(s).offset().left= 0 // should not be
$(s).css('padding-top') //is undefined.
```

These are right when a web page is loaded outside of the iframe. Tried everything I've found relating to the issue but no solution works.

Appreciate some help.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `.offset()` and `.css()`?

Comment: I have simulated pages on the charts. So to determine how many lines I can get on a page, I interrogate other elements to see how much space i have on a "page". With .css() i can margins and paddings for example. Offset allows me to check heights. I'm going to this much trouble so I can set up pages for different devices and screen orientations.

Comment: Where are the values set for the CSS properties queried? Not certain what issue is?

Comment: i'm using "if (s) alert ($(s).attr("id"));" to test what metrics are not being processed.

[alert ($(s).offset().top)  = 0 //when it should be 5
alert ($(s).offset().left) = 0 // should not be
alert ($(s).css('padding-top') ) //is undefined.]

Comment: Why do you expect `$(s).offset().top` to be equal to `5`?

Comment: http://katoomba.musetech.com.au/apps/chords/

Comment: This will show you what i'm trying to achieve. Top of the page is offset by 5 to make it look more "page-like"

Comment: http://katoomba.musetech.com.au/apps/chords/setlist.html

Comment: The second link is with iframes. Double-click on the list and it will load a song into another tab. You can see this isn't loading properly

Comment: The linked page does not contain an `<iframe>` element

Comment: on the second link, double click on one of the items in the list. a new tab appears

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where is `top` set for the `<iframe>` element?

Comment: Just signed up today. Still trying to get my head around the formatting etc

Comment: No worries. See also jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net and plnkr https://plnkr.co

Comment: all initial formatting is set in the CSS file. Javascript is used to dynamically adjust

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue at one of the linked code editors?

Comment: Will try to.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was loading everything into jquery ui tab which turns out to be a hidden div until you click on the tab. So it was being created but not displayed so the metrics couldn't be determined